# how to change source level in DrJava

Tags: java, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I am attempting to run a switch function in my static method and I keep getting this error:

```
File: C:\Users\Darien Springer\Documents\Java\DaysInMonth.java  [line: 6]

Error: Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. 

Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted
```

I have looked up several guides but none of them seem to indicate how to change the source level to be above 1.7. When I look in the settings it says DrJava is running on Java version 1.8 so I am confused as to what the issue is. Here is my class file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class DaysInMonth { 

   public static void daysInaMonth (int year_number, String month_name) {
      if(year_number % 4 != 0 || month_name != "February") {
         switch(month_name) {
            case "January":
            case "March":
            case "May":
            case "July":
            case "August":
            case "October":
            case "December":
                System.out.print("31");
               break;
            case "April":
            case "June":
            case "September":
            case "November":
                System.out.print("30");
               break;
            case "February":
               System.out.print("28");
               break;
            default:
               System.out.print("Please input ");
               break;
         }  
      }
      else {
           System.out.print("29");
      }


   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must download and install new jdk version from Oracle webpage.

Comment: I'll see if that's the issue. Thank you.